# One Zone file for two domains

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have to manage two domains : 
compagny.com
copagny.bigcompagny.com

I use Bind9 on Debian Lenny.

I want to use one Zone file for both domains.

- If I ask for server.compagny.com, it will give me address 10.0.0.1
- If I ask for server.compagny.bigcompagny.com, it will give me the same address 10.0.0.1

I don't want to create twice the same files for my DNS Server :  Too hard to maintain.

How can I do that ?

Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just list the same file twice in your `named.conf`:

```
zone "example.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "example.com";
};

zone "subsidiary.example.com" IN {
    type master;
    file "example.com";
};
```

However - you'll have to be clever with the contents of your zone file:

1. Don't include a `$ORIGIN` statement - it's implicit from the config file
2. Use '`@`' to refer to the implicit `$ORIGIN`
3. Use relative domain names (not FQDNs) as appropriate.
4. Use FQDNs when it actually matters which domain is returned

Comment: this line : 
@  IN  SOA  ns1.example.com. hostmaster.example.com.

should stay the same ?

Comment: That's up to you - you could just use `@ IN SOA ns1 hostmaster ( ... )`, and then the `$ORIGIN` will be automatically appended, giving you the "right" SOA for each domain.  That's covered by items #3 and #4 above.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one zone for for multiple domains by specifying the same zone file for each domain in named.conf. However, the examples you give aren't domains, they're hosts. The only way I can see to do that easily is with wildcards. Any other way is far harder to maintain than simply having separate zone files.